# Ubuntu-Server.18 Добрый вечер случай удалил папку user1. (Как реанимировать )

Tags: linux, ubuntu, администрирование

**Ubuntu-Server.18**

Добрый вечер случай удалил папку home/ user1.
(Там нет не чего важного)

Только каждый раз пишет

> "No directory logging in with home"

Есть вариант ? Не пересоздать пользователя ? ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

......

```
mkdir -p /home/user1
cp -r /etc/skel/. /home/user1
chown userd1:userd1 /home/user1
```